function redefined in .emacs gets overwritten at startup
I redefine the function rmail-make-in-reply-to-field in my .emacs but I noticed that when I restart emacs and invoke rmail then my redefined function is overwritten by the standard until I call M-x load-file .emacs. This must be cause rmail defines this function when is invoked. Rmail variables instead are not redefined to their standard value when I start rmail.
First I'd like to know if this redefinition only happen with functions, and variables customized in my .emacs via either
(setq ... ...) or
(custom-set-variables '(... ...) ... )
are always preserved (not just talking about rmail here, but in general). I hope so! If yes, then how can I personalise a function without having to reload my .emacs constantly? There must be a better way than redefining it in .emacs, given what happened!

Try:
(with-eval-after-load 'rmail
    ;; Put the re-definition of your function here.
    )

The with-eval-after-load executes its body after the expected file is loaded.

Do I need to do this for variables too?

@user43824 No. (setopt VARIABLE VALUE) is good enough.

@user43824 If this answer solves your problem, consider accept it. thx

Sure; in the meantime I was trying to figure out whether with-eval-after-load is the canonical way of modifying these functions, or there's more "guided" ways like custom-set-variable but for functions. Any thoughts?

@user43824 It's exactly the recommended way.
